# Android : Fragment onCreateView method call again after orientation changed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I implement the app which has two layout for landscape and portrait mode. The layout for landscape is in the **layout-land**. I have the `fragment1` for portrait layout and `fragment2` for landscape layouts. I override the `onCreateView` in each fragment.

I have static variable to know the current fragment. I assgined in the `onCreateView` (1 for fragment1 and 2 for fragment2).

My problem is that the static value is still 1 when the orientation is landscape mode.

I debugged the orientation of application. When I change orientation portrait into landscape, fragment2's `onCreateView` method called first and then the fragment1's `onCreateView` method called again. The static value has overridden.

I don't know why did `fragment1` `onCreateView` method call after the `fragment2` called? I want to assign the right value for right fragment.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don`t need to save something!
Just let your activity handle the orientation change.
In AndroidManifest.xml put this

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the bundle and must override onsavedinstance method so that the activityis not createdagain.

First when orientation is changed android checks for the savedinstancestate and calls onSavedInstanceState method if implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onCreate of each fragment you have to call

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(requestedOrientation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have two special `Fragment` implementations, if your Fragments have a different 'business logic' in landscape and portrait. If they just have a different layout then use 1 Fragment implementation, and create 2 layouts, one for each orientation.

Instantiate and create your `Fragments` in `Activity.onCreate()`. But do not save the current `Fragment` in a static variable. Instead ask the `FragmentManager` if a `Fragment` has already been added:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Fragment myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myTag");
    if(myFragment == null){
        //no Fragment has been added
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(new MyFragment1(), "myTag");
        transaction.commit();
    }else{
        //the fragment has been added already, possibley before orientation change
        //you could check its type and replace it
        if(fragment instanceof MyFragment1){

        }else if(fragment instanceof MyFragment2{

        }
    }
}
```